# A word for "who does what"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

A word for "who does what".  For example, "I need to understand who does what in the company".

Comment: What words have you considered, and why are they not suitable?  Why is "who does what" not suitable?  If you are learning English, try the English Language Learners site at http://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: *The* Responsibilities / Roles / Positions *within*?

Comment: "the distribution/division of roles".

Comment: ***Roles. and Responsibilities*** “R&Rs” for short.  I need to understand everyone’s  R&Rs within the company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fairly close approximation to your request would be **responsibility** (I need to understand people's responsibilities within the company), or **job functions** (I need to understand the job functions of people within the company).

However, a more compact version would be

> I need to understand the company organization.